# If the null-coalescing operator is supposed to protect against null values, why would Visual Studio or ReSharper suggest a possible null solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, collections, null, resharper

So here's a generic function that I had

```
int SomeArray(IEnumerable<int> array, int size) 
{
    int product = 1
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        product *= array[i];
    }
    return product
}
```

Visual Studio or ReSharper, I'm not sure which, suggested that I change `array[i]` to enumerate as array by changing the function to be

```
var enumerable = array as int[] ?? array.ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    product *= enumerable[i];
}
```

The problem I see is that the passed in `array` could be null and Visual Studio does warn against a possible `System.NullReferenceException` being thrown.

The real question is that the idea of the null-coalescing operator is that if the operand on the left is null then the operand on the right will be used.

If I do `var enumerable = array as int[] ?? array.ToArray() ?? new int[size];` The `new int[size]` is marked as being not needed because the according to Visual Studio the stuff on the left could never be null. When I can clearly force the passed in array to be null.

So what am I not getting here?

Comment: Your original code doesn't even compile (your "array" that's not an array doesn't have an indexer).

Comment: @Servy It is why visual studio prompted the change.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `for` loop in the first place, since you don't have an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
var enumerable = array as int[] ?? array.ToArray();
```

Can never be null (according to Resharper), because if `array` is null - it will throw an exception, and `ToArray` is known by Resharper to never return null (there is special database of methods Resharper knows cannot return null, and you can mark your own with `NotNull` attribute).

If you are interested about that Resharper "database" (called external annotations, which is just xml file), here is the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/ExternalAnnotations/blob/a74a8a47190cf7f8f950f4addd6bfef0cf2722a6/Annotations/.NETFramework/System.Core/2.0.5.0.Contracts.xml) where you can see:

```
 <member
    name="M:System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray``1(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{``0})">
     <parameter name="source">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
     </parameter>
     <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />          
</member>
```

Where you can see that `ToArray()` is marked with `NotNull` attribute. Because of that, Resharper is sure `ToArray()` cannot return null (while in theory it could).

If you want to use your expression, you need to check array for null, like this (if you can use C# 6):

```
var enumerable = array as int[] ?? array?.ToArray() ?? new int[size];
```

Or this:

```
var enumerable = array as int[] ?? (array != null ? array.ToArray() : new int[size]);
```

Comment: So ReSharper isn't at fault in using the null-coalescing operator, but it just didn't complete the null protection?

Comment: Well it wasn't null protection in the first place. Your original code is invalid and will not compile, so Resharper suggested a fix. It did not promise any null protection. In this case '??' is used not to protect from null but as a minor optimization (to not copy array if value is already array).

Comment: Note that if you just did `foreach (var item in array.Take(size))` as you should - you won't struggle with all this :)

Answer (score 1):

If `array` was `null` then that line of code would call `array.ToArray` on that `null` value, and it'll throw an argument null exception.

`ToArray` will never return a `null` value (even if a `null` value is provided) which is why your array constructor can never be called.